# How to buy item from Soomla storefront?

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, soomla

In the open source framework, this is the code to buy item:

```
[StoreInventory buyItemWithItemId:@"[itemId]"]
```

What is the equivalent code to buy item from storefront?

https://github.com/soomla/ios-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Storefront, the code to buy an item is:
`([StoreInventory buyItemWithItemId:@"your_item_id"])`.

See http://answers.soom.la/t/closed-storeinventory-item/270